# Custom Action on a generic List without a Content Type

Tags: list, content-type, custom-action

Can I define a SharePoint ribbon or Menu custom action on a generic list without a content type?

I've tried the following with no luck. It doesn't show up in the ribbon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
    Id="PushToNavAction"
    RegistrationType="List"
    GroupId="ActionsMenu"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
    Sequence="1000"
    ControlAssembly="Accreda.TicketingSystem.Receivers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0db9e3602d4c2d7d"
    ControlClass="Accreda.TicketingSystem.Receivers.CustomActions.PushToNav"
    Description="Push this SharePoint job to Navision."
    RegistrationId="10002"    
    RequireSiteAdministrator="false"
    Title="PushToNavAction"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <!-- Define the (UI) button to be used for this custom action -->
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="ContentTypeTest.Button"
          Image32by32="~site/_layouts/Accreda.TicketingSystem.Core/Images/UploadToNav_16x16.gif"
          Image16by16="~site/_layouts/Accreda.TicketingSystem.Core/Images/UploadToNav_32x32.gif"
          Sequence="95"
          LabelText="Push to Navision"
          Description="Push this SharePoint job to Navision."
          TemplateAlias="o2"
          Command="ContentTypeCommand"
          CommandType="General"
          />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <!-- Define the action expected on the button click -->
        <CommandUIHandler Command="{4E2F5DC0-FE2C-4466-BB2D-3ED0D1917763}" CommandAction="" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways how to do it:

1. Add a custom action and set `RegistrationType="List"` and  `RegistrationId="ListTemplateID"`. E.g.:

`<CustomAction
        Id="DMS.ContentTypes.RegistryOwnerCustomAction"
        RegistrationType="List"
        RegistrationId="101"
        Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.ListEdit"
        GroupId="GeneralSettings"
        Sequence="15001"
        Rights="ManageLists"
        Title="$Resources:DMS.ContentTypes,RegistryOwnerCustomAction_Title;" >
        <UrlAction Url="javascript:window.location= '{SiteUrl}/_layouts/DMS/SetRegistryOwner.aspx?List={ListId}&amp;Source='+ escape(window.location)"/>
</CustomAction>`

2. Add a custom control to `AdditionalPageHead` and then override it's `OnLoad` method. Trim ribbon, add new buttons or menu items from there. E.g.:

`<Control
   ControlAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
   ControlClass="BTMU.CustomActions.PageCustomActions"
   Sequence="1000"
   Id="AdditionalPageHead">
</Control>`

`protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
 {
    this.EnsureChildControls();
    base.OnLoad(e);
    this.Visible = false;
    if (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Edit)
    {
        SPRibbon ribbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        this.RegisterJavaScript(ribbon);
        ShowCustomActions(ribbon);
    }
 }`

Continue with article series from [here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html) on how to add button to the ribbon programmatically. Advantage of the latter is that you can do various checks more easily (e.g. list URLs, various conditions for enable/disable commands etc.):

2013 is very similar to 2010 except some of the Ribbon Locations are different which you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb802730.aspx).